# Oracle: "I/O: Connection reset" while compiling a procedure on a specific server

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, connection, reset

on one of our servers, while compiling:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_KO
IS
TABLE_SUFFIX_     VARCHAR2 (100);
  QUERY_DROP_ VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
  TABLE_SUFFIX_ := 'TABLE_SUFFIX';
  QUERY_DROP_ := 'DROP TABLE ' || 'TMP_' || TABLE_SUFFIX_;
END;
```

I get the following error:

> `I/O Error: Connection reset`

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Are you seeing this frequently? Or an intermittent issue? Connection could be reset due to many cause? have you checked whether DB server is running or not?

Comment: If it happens every time on just that server, are there any [DDL triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS2063) on that database/schema?

Comment: Hi Rahul> this error occurs always when I try to compile that procedure on that server.

Comment: Hi Alex Poole> I run this query: `code`select TRIGGERING_EVENT FROM USER_TRIGGERS;`code` but all results were INSERT,UPDATA or DELETE. I've used my standard user (the one with which I compile the procedure).

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that in your case you're disallowed to create a procedure by a DDL trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bcs_trigger
BEFORE CREATE
ON SCHEMA
DECLARE
  oper ddl_log.operation%TYPE;
BEGIN
  -- in some case
  DBMS_SERVICE.DISCONNECT_SESSION(my_session);      
END bcs_trigger;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like I had the same, or at least a similar, problem. I had already successfully created/compiled the procedure and later returned to make some changes using SQL Developer (17.2.0.188). When attempting to compile the procedure I received the same error (Connection Reset).

It was only after creating a new procedure by copying blocks of code was I able to isolate the 2-3 lines that seemed to be causing the problem. A slight rewrite of one of the lines (by using different variable names) seemed to do the trick.

There was nothing about the lines in question that seemed to stand out. Simple for loop using a SQL statement.

Still don't know the root cause of the problem, but making minor changes to the code seemed to allow it to compile.